# jenkins plugin - Starting and stopping a Stage from inside a plugin

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

First, some background why I want this crazy thing. I'm building a Plugin in Jenkins that provides an API for scripts that are started from a pipeline-script to independently communicate with jenkins.
For example a shell-script can then tell jenkins to start a new stage from the running script.

I've got the communication between the script and Jenkins working, but the problem is that I now want to try and start a stage from a callback in my code but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

**Stuff I've tried and failed at:**

*Start a new `StageStep.java`*
I can't seem to find a way to correctly instantiate and inject the step into the lifecycle. I've looked into `DSL.java`, but cant seem to get to an instance to call `invokeStep()`, nor was I able to find out how to instantiate `DSL.java` with the right environment.

*Look at `StageStepExecution.java` and do what it does.*
It seems to either invoke the body with an Environment Variable and nothing else, or set some actions and save the state in a config file when it has no body. I could not find out how the Pipeline: Stage View Plugin hooks into this, but it doesn't seem to read the config file. I've tried setting the Actions (even the inner class through reflection) but that did not seem to do anything.

*Inject a custom string as Groovy body and call it with `csc.newBodyInvoker()`*
A hacky solution I came up with was just generating the groovy script and running it like the ParallelStep does. But the sandbox does not allow me to call `new GroovyShell().evaluate("")`, and If I approve that call, the 'stage' step throws a MissingMethodException. So I also do not instatiate the script with the right environment. Providing the EnvironmentExpander does not make any difference.

*Referencing and modifying workflow/{n}.xml*
Changing the name of a stage in the relevant `workflow/{n}.xml` and rebooting the server updates the name of the stage, but modifying my custom stage to look like a regular one does not seem to add the step as a stage.

**Stuff I've researched:**

- If some other plugin does something like this, but I couldn't find any example of plugins starting other steps.
- How Jenkins handles the scripts and starts the steps, but It seems as though every step is directly called through the method name after the script is parsed, and I found no way to hook into this.
- Other plugins using the StageView through other methods, but I could not find any.
- add an AtomNode as a head onto the running thread, but I couldn't find how to replace/add the head and am hesitant to mess with jenkins' threading.

I've spent multiple days on this seemingly trivial call, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

So the latest thing I tried actually worked, and is displayed correctly, but it ain't pretty.
I basically reimplemented the implementation of `DSL.invokeStep()`, which required me to use reflection A LOT. This is not safe, and will break with any changes of course so I'll open an issue in the Jenkins' ticket system in the hopes they will add a public interface for doing this. I'm just hoping this won't give me any weird side-effects.

```
// First, get some environment stuff
CpsThread cpsThread = CpsThread.current();
CpsFlowExecution currentFlowExecution = (CpsFlowExecution) getContext().get(FlowExecution.class);

// instantiate the stage's descriptor
StageStep.DescriptorImpl stageStepDescriptor = new StageStep.DescriptorImpl();

// now we need to put a new FlowNode as the head of the step-stack. This is of course not possible directly,
// but everything is also outside of the sandbox, so putting the class in the same package doesn't work
// get the 'head' field
Field cpsHeadField = CpsThread.class.getDeclaredField("head");
cpsHeadField.setAccessible(true);
Object headValue = cpsHeadField.get(cpsThread);
// get it's value
Method head_get = headValue.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("get");
head_get.setAccessible(true);
FlowNode currentHead = (FlowNode) head_get.invoke(headValue);

// crate a new StepAtomNode starting at the current value of 'head'.
FlowNode an = new StepAtomNode(currentFlowExecution, stageStepDescriptor, currentHead);

// now set this as the new head.
Method head_setNewHead = headValue.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setNewHead", FlowNode.class);
head_setNewHead.setAccessible(true);
head_setNewHead.invoke(headValue, an);

// Create a new CpsStepContext, and as the constructor is protected, use reflection again
Constructor<?> declaredConstructor = CpsStepContext.class.getDeclaredConstructors()[0];
declaredConstructor.setAccessible(true);
CpsStepContext context = (CpsStepContext) declaredConstructor.newInstance(stageStepDescriptor,cpsThread,currentFlowExecution.getOwner(),an,null);

stageStepDescriptor.checkContextAvailability(context); // Good to check stuff I guess

// Create a new instance of the step, passing in arguments as a Map
Map<String, Object> stageArguments = new HashMap<>();
stageArguments.put("name", "mynutest");
Step stageStep = stageStepDescriptor.newInstance(stageArguments);

// so start the damd thing
StepExecution execution = stageStep.start(context);

// now that we have a callable instance, we set the step on the Cps Thread. Reflection to the rescue
Method mSetStep = cpsThread.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setStep", StepExecution.class);
mSetStep.setAccessible(true);
mSetStep.invoke(cpsThread, execution);

// Finally. Start running the step
execution.start();
```